# Outsourcing chips manufacture; do they get pirated?

Tags: cpu

When Intel or Apple outsources their electronics to Asia, what prevents the outsource vendor from copying the design and making a knock-off product?

Comment: "Knockoff" shoes can be sold pretty much anywhere. It's harder to find a buyer for a CPU.

Comment: For most of ICs, this happens, but not for the real complex ones that actually need knowhow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't matter where the chips are fabbed. Many Intel chips are designed in China and India anyway. Or in Israel. What prevents the complex chips from pirating is their built-in complexity and built-in security.

To begin, the chips are fabricated from tape-out files that are used to create photomasks. One can't get a functional chip without its hardware model, the RTL, and one can't reverse the RTL from photomask pictures. Even if someone steals the RTL database, the chip layout is done by a different team with highly secured library database and tested under a dedicated verification suite, so one can't reproduce the usable tape-out files.

Then the chips are packaged at entirely different location or country, which requires a different set of tools and programs to run them.

The chip itself is not usable until it gets binned and configured with irreversible fuses, which is done by completely different team and tools. The chip is still not usable until its internal service processors are programmed with corresponding microcodes, which were developed and executed at completely different facility and different teams. Without going through all patches a BIOS can't configure any internal peripherals/PHYs, especially if most configuration functions are secured by encryption that is individual for each chip.

Unless you have all this infrastructure of 50,000 hardware/software engineers working together, you can't expect to get a working "knock-off" product.

Answer (score 2):

Approximately 75% of Intel's semiconductor fabrication is performed in the USA and only old generations (65nm) in China.

Apple also do not trust China for foundry work but did trust Samsung and now turning to a Taiwanese foundry, TSMC to make future chips with 10nm fabs for A10X, A11.

Comment: Years back, I recall some discussion between Intel employees on a plane trip about how Andy Grove was requiring the newer equipment to be pulled out of China and re-installed in USA.